# going from one tab to another in testing in protractor

Tags: protractor, cucumber

i am shifting control from tab 1 to tab 2 and closing tab1 so that i can perform operations on tab 2 but when i execute this section i get an error. ie;
Reference Error: window is not defined
Can anyone help me with this code?

```
  browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) { //getting all tabs 

        var secondWindowHandle = handles[1]; //tab1
        var firstWindowHandle = handles[0];  //tab2
        browser.switchTo().window(secondWindowHandle).then(function () { 
        //the focus moves on new tab
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;    
            window(firstWindowHandle).close(); //closing tab 1
        });
    });
```

Comment: you want to close the 1st tab, and then work on the 2nd tab?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below way to close tab 1 and work on tab 2.

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) { 
        var secondWindowHandle = handles[1]; //tab1
        var firstWindowHandle = handles[0];  //tab2
        browser.switchTo().window(firstWindowHandle).then(function() {
            return browser.close()
        }).then(function() {
                return browser.switchTo().window(secondWindowHandle);
        })
    });
```